# list[int, ...] is not working while tuple[int, ...] is working while i'm using mypy . Please explain why i am getting the error

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

```
a: list[int, ...] = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(a) # i am getting error while running on mypy

b: tuple[int, ...] = (1,2,3,4,5)
print(b) # runs without error on mypy
```

1. Please Explain why mypy raises error on list but not on tuple ?

Answer (score 0):

`tuple[T, ...]` means a tuple of any length of elements of type `T`.

There is no such construct for `list` as lists are homogenous. `list` accepts only one type parameter that specifies the list element type.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to specify a list of integers use `list[int]` instead of `list[int, ...]`.

There is no ellipsis (`...`) for lists.

For more info, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List).